# bootstrap работает, но не на всех классах. Текст делает красивее, но панели не добавляет

Tags: bootstrap

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading">Заголовок</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Текст</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">Заголовок</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Текст</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Заголовок</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Текст</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Может я что-то не так делаю, новенький в этом деле могу и налажать, не серчайте уж

Comment: Код надо прикладывать текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: Исправил, есть идеи почему не хотят работать панели?

Comment: По Вашему коду не возможно дать ответ на вопрос — приложите весь выдаваемый HTML, подключите Bootstrap, и его прямо здесь можно будет выполнить и посмотреть.